# Integrating Solr with web application

Tags: solr, lucene

**Context:**
I have a web application that serves content via RESTful web services
I need to provide a search functionality

This is what I have in mind. Am I on the right track or way off ?

**Index seed client:**
This component will poll the Application at repeated intervals for data
(I have a WS which returns an XML response)
And then Post the XML to a EMS

**Queue Listener:**
The Queue Listener will convert the domain XML into Solr doc
And the post the document to Solr to be indexed

**Search client:**
The client will make a search request to my web application with query parameters
The web application will forward the request to Solr
Solr returns search results to my web application
My web application returns the result back to the client

**Alternate flow ?**
The search client talks to Solr directly and does the search.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Searching will depend on your implementation choice of solr server. If you use embbededSolrServer you will need to query via your web client then calling sol. If you are using an httpsolrserver then you can query solr directly.

It also depends on how you want to return the results. 
As solr documents? 
Or your own interpretation of a solr document? 
The later would have to be serviced by your web application